# two layouts for NextJs ( app router ) application

Tags: next.js

I am using NextJs 14 ( App Router version ). I want to create a login and register page layout and a separate layout for the main application. My root layout looks like this

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={rubik.className} >
        <Providers>
          {children}

        </Providers>
        
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

I have another layout in `app/overview`. Now if I make this RootLayout layout for my login and registration page, this appears in the application layout. How can I separate it? How can I have two layouts which does not overlap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make your root `app/layout.tsx` shared for the app as basic as:

```js
export default function RootLayout({children}) {
  return (
     <html>
        <body>{children}</body>
     </html>
   )
}
```

2. Create a folder with `(this-structure)` in app then add `login` and `register` to it. This is called Route Group.

```markdown
app/
- layout.tsx        <-- root layout 

- (auth)/
  - layout.tsx      <-- auth layout 
  - login/page.tsx
  - register/page.tsx
  - ...

- overview
  - layout.tsx      <-- app layout
  - page.tsx
  - about/
    - page.tsx
  - ...
```

Learn more about route group:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups

Comment: yes, thanks for this. I had to change a bit the config file. const nextConfig = {
  
  async redirects() {

  return [
    {
      source: '/',
      destination: '/login',
      permanent: false,
    },
  ]
},

};

Now it works

Comment: This redirect should be in the Middleware not next.config